# Reduce Airy's equation to a bessel equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to reduce the following Airy's equation $y''+x^py=0$ and demonstrate that his order is $v=\frac{1}{p+2}$, through a substitution $y(x)=\sqrt{(x)}u(x)$ (1) and then by changing the variable $z=\frac{2}{2+p}x^{\frac{2+p}{2}}$ (2). I derived (1) and replaced it in the ODE, and tried to change the variables by the chain rule using the expression (2), but I couldn't solve it. Am I doing something wrong or is something missing?